# increase granularity of filter subscription notification frequency

Tags: feature-request, email-notification

Here's a snapshot of the current options for managing filter e-mail notifications:

[image: filter email updates]

Whereas i'd love to have more options to manage my notifications frequency:

[image: filter email updates extended]

The most desired feature being a synchronous-like notification mechanism, i.e. selecting the "When Posted" option.

Comment: That's asking for a lot of the SO servers, to send an email to you any time there is a question posted... I personally would hate it, it'd clog up my inbox.

Comment: The mail server also won't like it.

Comment: why the downvote? it's a **request**, and i wasn't referring to the solution implementation, just proposing what i think is a desired feature.

Comment: another thing - this feature could be limited for use with new filters or those with no more than a few questions.

Comment: @EliranMalka Votes indicate community support for a feature, which factors into how SE prioritizes their development resources. Downvoting a feature request indicates members of the community don't want SE to devote resources to this over other, ostensibly more important requests.

Comment: i see, thanks for clarifying.

Comment: [Downvotes indeed mean something slightly different on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences)

Comment: @Lix thank you. it's nice to know.

Comment: +1, but only for the Dr Seuss reference, not for the request.